# Abstract a synchronous function with its Future counterpart

Tags: scala, future

I wrote a very simple mechanism that only allows a `max` number of function calls during a given number of `seconds`. See it as a basic rate limiter.

It takes the execution to limit as an argument and returns the return value of that original execution.

The problem is that executions can be synchronous (of type `=> A`) or asynchronous (of type `=> Future[A]`) and that leads to two extremely similar functions:

```
case class Limiter[A](max: Int, seconds: Int) {
  private val queue = Queue[Long]()

  def limit(value: => A): Option[A] = {
    val now = System.currentTimeMillis()
    if (queue.length == max) {
      val oldest = queue.head
      if (now - oldest < seconds * 1000) return None
      else queue.dequeue()
    }
    queue.enqueue(now)
    Some(value)
  }

  def limitFuture(future: => Future[A]): Future[Option[A]] = {
    val now = System.currentTimeMillis()
    if (queue.length == max) {
      val oldest = queue.head
      if (now - oldest < seconds * 1000) return Future(None)
      else queue.dequeue()
    }
    future.map { x =>
      queue.enqueue(now)
      Some(x)
    }
  }
}
```

(I am not actually using `Option` but a set of types I defined, just using `Option` for simplicity sake)

Examples of execution:

```
// Prevent more than 5 runs/minute. Useful for example to prevent email spamming
val limit = Limit[Boolean](5, 60)
val result = limitFuture { sendEmail(...) } // `sendEmail` returns a future

// Prevent more than 1 run/hour. Useful for example to cache HTML response
val limit = Limit[String](1, 3600)
val limit { getHTML(...) } // `getHTML` returns the HTML as a string directly
```

**How can I refactor these methods to avoid repetition?** Later needs might include other argument types and not only direct type + `Future`d type, so I'd like to keep my options open if it's possible.

The only "solution" I could come up with so far is to replace `limit`:

```
def limit(value: => A): Option[A] = {
  Await.result(limitFuture(Future.successful(value)), 5.seconds)
}
```

Well, it works, but it feels backwards. I would rather have the `=> A` being the base version that other methods extend or, even better, a generic (private) method that both `limit` and `limitFuture` could extend.
Actually, it would be even better-er if a single `limit` function could take care of this regardless of argument but I doubt it's possible.

Comment: Do you plan to use your code in multi-threaded environment? If yes, then you have race condition. If no, then you can move `enqueue` before future.map in async variant. Then you will be able to simply extract all common logic in a separate generic function.

Comment: I'm not planning to run this in multi-threaded environment, but since it's a learning exercise for me, I'm happy to improve and discover how not to make the same mistake the day I need to :) I cannot extract the `enqueue` from the `future.map` because only successful runs should be enqueued. In the example above, if `sendEmail` fails for some reason, that attempt should not be counted towards the limit. Makes sense?

Comment: If you only have a single thread it's not clear why you want to have async api at all.  Anyway, currently your methods are semantically different. In the first method `now` is enqueued *before* lazy `value` is calculated, while in the second method it's after future is successful, as you described.

Comment: "If you only have a single thread it's not clear why you want to have async api at all." > Fair point. 2 reasons: `sendEmail` is using an external library to send the email, which returns a `Future`, and I decided to just pass it around. Though I could be blocking in `sendEmail` and be done with it. Other reason: this is initially an exercise for me to learn how to do these things. I could go around, but that would teach me when I actually need it :D

Comment: "Anyway, currently your methods are semantically different." > That's very true, thanks. I need to replace `queue.enqueue(now); Some(value)` with `val option = Some(value); queue.enqueue(now); option`. Does that seem better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can condense this down to one method with an implicit parameter handling the differences:

```
trait Limitable[A, B] {
  type Out
  def none: Out
  def some(b: B, f: () => Unit): Out
}

implicit def rawLimitable[A]: Limitable[A, A] = new Limitable[A, A] {
  type Out = Option[A]
  def none = None
  def some(a: A, f: () => Unit): Out = {
    f()
    Some(a)
  }
}
implicit def futureLimitable[A]: Limitable[A, Future[A]] = new Limitable[A, Future[A]] {
  type Out = Future[Option[A]]
  def none = Future(None)
  def some(future: Future[A], f: () => Unit): Out = future.map { a =>
    f()
    Some(a)
  }
}

case class Limiter[A](max: Int, seconds: Int) {
  private val queue = Queue[Long]()

  def limit[B](in: => B)(implicit l: Limitable[A, B]): l.Out = {
    val now = System.currentTimeMillis()
    if (queue.length == max) {
      val oldest = queue.head
      if (now - oldest < seconds * 1000) return l.none
      else queue.dequeue()
    }
    l.some(in, {() => queue.enqueue(now)})
  }
}
```

And use it like:

```
val limit = Limit[String](1, 3600)
limit.limit("foo")
limit.limit(Future("bar"))
```

Comment: That's great stuff, I'm going to play with this, thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately, I am unable to compile this. While the code above itself compiles, using the returned values does not. To work with the examples given in questions, I am trying to pattern match the values against `Option[A]` or `Future[Option[A]]` (implementations of `type Out`) like so: `limiter.limit(fetcher) match { case None => ...; case Some(...) }`. Problem is, compilation fails with `pattern type is incompatible with expected type; found: None.type; required: Limitable[A,A]#Out`. Any trick I can use to make this work?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Applicative` typeclass from `cats` or `scalaz`. Applicative, among other things, lets you lift a value into some context `F` (using `pure`) and is also a functor, so you can use `map` on `F[A]`.

Currently you want it for `Id` and `Future` types (you need ExecutionContext in scope for Future applicative to work). It will work for things like `Vector` or `Validated`, tho you might have problems adding custom collection types.

```
import cats._, implicits._
import scala.concurrent._
import scala.collection.mutable.Queue

case class Limiter[A](max: Int, seconds: Int) {
  private val queue = Queue[Long]()

  def limitA[F[_]: Applicative](value: => F[A]): F[Option[A]] = {
    val now = System.currentTimeMillis()
    if (queue.length == max) {
      val oldest = queue.head
      if (now - oldest < seconds * 1000) return none[A].pure[F]
      else queue.dequeue()
    }
    value.map { x =>
      queue.enqueue(now)
      x.some
    }
  }

  // or leave these e.g. for source compatibility
  def limit(value: => A): Option[A] = limitA[Id](value)
  def limitFuture(future: => Future[A])(implicit ec: ExecutionContext): Future[Option[A]] = limitA(future)
}
```

Notes:
I'm using `none[A]` instead of `None: Option[A]` and `a.some` instead of `Some(a): Option[A]`. These helpers are available in both `cats` and `scalaz` and you need them because `F[_]` here is not defined as covariant.

---

You have to specify `Id` as a type explicitly, e.g. `.limitA[Id](3)`. This is not the case with `Future`, however.

---

You `map` call is strange. It is parsed as:

```
future.map {
  queue.enqueue(now) // in current thread
  x => Some(x)
}
```

Which is the same as

```
queue.enqueue(now) // in current thread
future.map {
  x => Some(x)
}
```

Comment: Whoa, lots of nice things in here! A _lot_ of what you used/described is unknown to me so I'm definitely going to educate myself about all that, thanks a lot. In the meantime, I'm probably going to go for @JoeK's solution if I can apply it in my case (I simplified my examples for the SO question) but really I wish I could accept both answers :)

Comment: "You map call is strange. It is parsed as: [...] Which is the same as [...]" > Not really the same though, because if the future fails, I do not want to enqueue the execution time. Per [the API doc for `Future#map`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/concurrent/Future.html): "Creates a new future by applying a function to the successful result of this future."

Comment: @astorije in your code the value will be enqueued even if future fails. The function you use for `map` is not the whole `{...}` block, but the return value of that block (function `x => Some(x)`). The code above it will be executed before doing `map`. Compare to my version above.

Comment: Well I'll be damned! Somehow I have thought so far that `future.map { queue.enqueue(now); Some(_) }` expands into `future.map { x => queue.enqueue(now); Some(x) }` (what I meant), and not `future.map { queue.enqueue(now); x => Some(x) }`!! Sorry to get off-topic, but would you be able to explain how so? I spent quite some time online trying to find a good read on the details of that expansion and found nothing, would you have a pointer on this, by any chance? Thanks for notiving that anyway, I'm updating the question!